# browser print <IMG> with text in it?

Tags: html, printing

In my project, I need to gnerate and render a `<IMG>` in the html and print it out.

The `<IMG>` will have some text in it..

This `<IMG>` is generated by my javascript code, therefore I have full control of the height and width of the image.

My question is, what height/width should I render the `<IMG>` with so that when the browser is printing it, it does not try to resize the `<IMG>` in anyway. So that the texts won't appear blurry on print.

I think I can assume that the user will be printing on letter size papers with default margin.

Comment: The same height and width as the actual pixels in the image of course.

Comment: The <IMG> is controlled by myself. I want to make sure that my <IMG> occupies the whole width.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the properties of your image file and get the height/width of your image.(If it looks how you want when you open that file). Then use those dimensions when printing the image out... Basically what Quentin said.

Comment: Hey, i just added a few more conditions. The image is generated by myself. And i want to make sure that the <IMG> fills the width of the page (actually a <div> but for simplicity we can assume I just want to fill the page horizontally)